# Tunnelling from one SSH connection into another one

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I have a machine called `ic` that I can ssh to. There is another machine, `fw`, that is on a completely different VLAN, and I cannot talk to it. `ic` is on both my VLAN *and* the VLAN that `fw` uses, and so my usual procedure for sshing to fw is to ssh into `ic` and from there ssh into `fw`. If I wanted to script this action, however, how could I get it to work?

I tried `ssh root@ic "ssh root@fw"`, but this results in the message `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`, and then I get three messages from `fw`, presumably because it has null input:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

What's the best way to script this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `ssh` doesn't allocate a pty when a command is given. For interactive use, you can override this by using the `-t` option.

For authentication, if you are using public keys and a properly configured `ssh-agent`, you can use the `-A` option to enable agent forwarding.

```
ssh -t -A user@ic ssh root@fw
```

<sub>(What's it with using *root* everywhere? Don't be lazy, create an account.)</sub>

---

Another method, using TCP forwarding over SSH:

First establish a connection to *`ic`* with the `-L` (local tunnel) option:

```
ssh -L 7890:fw:22 -fN user@ic
```

Now all connections to *`localhost:7890`* will be forwarded through *`ic`* to *`fw:22`*. (The port 7890 is arbitrary; you can pick any unused port you like.)

(The `-fN` options will make this connection keep running in background.)

Second, connect through the tunnel:

```
ssh root@localhost -p 7890
```

Comment: True, I don't need to be root on `ic`. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer. The local tunnel option allowed me to scp and git over a gateway, for which I continuously got the error messages in the question, and no other solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW you can do the same with putty, which also uses the `-t` option.

Answer (score 0):

Other method is using `ProxyCommand`:

```
ssh root@fw -o "ProxyCommand=ssh root@ic nc $FW_VLAN_IP %p"
```

This connects to `ic`, creates a netcat TCP proxy to `fw` and lends it to your local `ssh` client, which means that it will use your local authentication systems instead of the remote ones.